# DocuSign (sending email to client) ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign demo account to send a document as an email for signing to the client using C#. I am using the code in this link (https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#quickstart) to do that. But when I run the code it is not sending any email to the client and it is not showing any error too. I also tried posting the baseurl that it returns after authentication along with the envelope using HttpWebRequest and also with ajax. It didn't worked out too. Can anyone please help me with this ?

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

using DocuSign.eSign.Api;

using DocuSign.eSign.Model;

using DocuSign.eSign.Client;

namespace DocuSignTest
{

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

            // Enter your DocuSign credentials
            string Username = "pradeepp.wayne@gmail.com";
            string Password = "******";
            string IntegratorKey = "****************";

            // specify the document we want signed
            string SignTest1File = @"C://SamplePdfSign.pdf";
            // Enter recipient (signer) name and email address
            string recipientName = "PPradeep";
            string recipientEmail = "*****************";
            // instantiate api client with appropriate environment
            string basePath = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";
            // instantiate a new api client
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
            // set client in global config so we don't need to pass it to each API object
            Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;
            string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + Username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + Password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + IntegratorKey + "\"}";
            Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
            // we will retrieve this from the login() results
            string accountId = null;
            AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
            LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
            accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;

            Console.WriteLine("LoginInformation: {0}", loginInfo.ToJson());
            // Read a file from disk to use as a document
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(SignTest1File);

            EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envDef.EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Please sign this doc";
            // Add a document to the envelope
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
            doc.Name = "TestFile.pdf";
            doc.DocumentId = "1";

            envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
            envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

            // Add a recipient to sign the documeent
            Signer signer = new Signer();
            signer.Name = recipientName;
            signer.Email = recipientEmail;
            signer.RecipientId = "1";

            // must set |clientUserId| to embed the recipient
            signer.ClientUserId = "1234";
            // Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
            signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
            SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
            signHere.DocumentId = "1";
            signHere.PageNumber = "1";
            signHere.RecipientId = "1";
            signHere.XPosition = "100";
            signHere.YPosition = "150";
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);

            envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);

            // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
            envDef.Status = "sent";

            // Use the EnvelopesApi to create and send the signature request
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

            Console.WriteLine("EnvelopeSummary:\n{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelopeSummary));



        } //try
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What about your code? How would we know that your code matches with the documentation? Please add your relevant `code` to your question.

Comment: Can you please share the JSON request which is generated, you can capture the API logging in DS by following - https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging. My understanding is that may be you are using Embedded Signing instead of Remote signing. DocuSign does not generate an email for embedded signing, you are calling embedded signing if you have added clientuserId in the json request for the signers.

Comment: Please check the code above I posted. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thank you @AmitKBist .I removed the clientuserid and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you comment-out (or remove altogether) this line from your code:

`signer.ClientUserId = "1234";`

When you specify **ClientUserId**, you're telling DocuSign not to send an email to the signer (because that signer is what DocuSign refers to as an *embedded* recipient).  If you remove **ClientUserId**, you're telling DocuSign that the signer is a *remote* recipient, so DocuSign will send a signing invitation email to that recipient.

Comment: Thank you so much Kim. Its working !. I am unaware that we cannot send email if we use embedded client.

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you please mark this answer as "accepted", so that others are more likely to benefit from this information in the future?  Thanks!